# Render React component with vanilla js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have my webapp that is happily using React.js

What I want to be able to do is for example from the console pick a react component, pass it some properties and get it to render out the html in the console. Can I do this?

Comment: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdomserver.rendertostring

Comment: Please take a shot at it, and when/if you get stuck, ask a question at that point sharing the code you've written.

Answer (score 1):

To access a React component from the console:

First off I would recommend getting react dev tools:

https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools

Its a browser extension that helps with the development React apps.

Once you have this, you can inspect an element, and access it in the console by using `$r.`